# How to use GSheet ArrayFormula function to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I've this list in GSheet

```
| A   | 8,6 |
| B   | 9,6 |
| C   | 7,5 |
| D   | 6,7 |
| E   | 9,5 |
| F   | 5,6 |
```

I can score the average with this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(IFNA(vlookup(trim(split(E2,",")),B2:C12,2,0))))
```

I've this result :

```
| A, C, F    | 7,23 |
| A, D       | 6,7  |
| C          | 7,5  |
| E, F       | 7,55 |
```

How to do the same in Excel ?

Comment: `E, F` should not be `15,1`  that is the sum not the average.

Comment: We are NOT a free conversion service. So maybe if you tell us what each part of your code is supposed to do in GSheet, and which part you cannot find a conversion equivalent in Excel we may be able to point you in the right direction. Otherwise, I believe this question should be closed for lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 dynamic array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(XLOOKUP(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(E2,",")),$A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,""))
```

[image]